# typedef fixed size array in c not working properly

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, typedef

I have a typedef of a char array to represent the position of a chess piece.

```
typedef char chessPos[2];
```

yet when i attempt to create an array of this type i run into unexplained behaviours.
for example.

```
  chessPos test= {'A','1'};
  chessPos test2= {'B','2'};
  chessPos* ptr = (chessPos*)(malloc(sizeof(chessPos) * 2));

  (*ptr)[0] = test[0];
  (*ptr)[1] = test[1];

  (*ptr+1)[0] = test2[0];
  (*ptr+1)[1] = test2[1];

  printf("(%c,%c)",*ptr[0],(*ptr)[1]);
  ptr++;
  printf("(%c,%c)",*ptr[0],(*ptr)[1]);
```

i will get:

```
(A,B)(2, )
```

instead of the expected:

```
(A,1)(B,2)
```

Comment: Operator precedence. `*ptr+1` first dereferences, then adds.

Comment: OT: I would prefer a more readable and bug resistant `chessPos* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * 2);` allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's karma: write really strange code and the universe will give you really strange bugs as revenge...

You have several issues with operator precedence. Fix it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char chessPos[2];

int main (void)
{
  chessPos test= {'A','1'};
  chessPos test2= {'B','2'};
  chessPos* ptr = (chessPos*)(malloc(sizeof(chessPos) * 2));

  (*ptr)[0] = test[0];
  (*ptr)[1] = test[1];

  (*(ptr+1))[0] = test2[0];
  (*(ptr+1))[1] = test2[1];

  printf("(%c,%c)",(*ptr)[0],(*ptr)[1]);
  ptr++;
  printf("(%c,%c)",(*ptr)[0],(*ptr)[1]);
}
```

You should however salvage this unreadable code by dropping the typedef and use multi-dimensional indexing instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char test[2]= {'A','1'};
  char test2[2]= {'B','2'};
  char (*ptr)[2] = malloc( sizeof(char[2][2]) );

  ptr[0][0] = test[0];
  ptr[0][1] = test[1];
  ptr[1][0] = test2[0];
  ptr[1][1] = test2[1];

  printf("(%c,%c)",ptr[0][0],ptr[0][1]);
  ptr++;
  printf("(%c,%c)",ptr[0][0],ptr[0][1]);
}
```

Always avoid hiding pointers and arrays behind typedefs!

Comment: I agree that the second example is much cleaner than the o.p. However, i don't agree what you say about the typedef. In the o.p. the typedef asserts that all array definitions have the same number of elements. In your answer please count, how many times you actually hardcoded the "2" value. Besides that, your second example should also work maintaining the typedef.

Comment: @pqans This is just a silly example, in real code you'd obviously use named constants. That's a poor rationale for using typedef.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a struct instead of an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char figureCoordinate_t;

typedef struct{
    figureCoordinate_t x;
    figureCoordinate_t y;
} figurePos_t;

void printFigurePos(figurePos_t *pos)
{
   printf("(%c, %c)", pos->x, pos->y); 
}

int main (void)
{
    figurePos_t testpos1 = {'A', '1'};
    figurePos_t testpos2 = {'B', '2'};
    figurePos_t *ptr = (figurePos_t*)malloc(2*sizeof(*ptr));

    ptr[0].x = testpos1.x;
    ptr[0].y = testpos1.y;

    ptr[1].x = testpos2.x;
    ptr[1].y = testpos2.y;

    printFigurePos(ptr);
    ++ptr;
    printFigurePos(ptr);

    free(ptr); // This was missing in the o.p.
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that the initialization code can refer to the definition in the way shown by Lundin (`sizeof *ptr`). I think it is a good idea and therefore just took it over.

Comment: "Why not use a struct instead of an array?" Because it means you get extra padding all over. Suppose you want contiguous allocation for whatever reason.

Comment: If the padding of 1 is a hard requirement depends on the memory constraints of the target system. This may be an argument. On the other hand, the struct may get extended by some other properties of a figure in a game. How do you do that using an array without defining named constants for every size and offset? Also, struct alignment of 1 is possible (using C11, alignas)

Answer (score -1):

For starters take into account that the type of the pointer `ptr` is `char ( * )[2]`.

Let's consider these expression statements

```
  (*ptr+1)[0] = test2[0];
  (*ptr+1)[1] = test2[1];
```

the type of the expression `*ptr` is `char[2]`  and the expression yields the first row of the dynamically allocated two dimensional array.

Used in expressions the array designator `*ptr` is implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to pointer to its first element.

Thus the sub-expression `*ptr+1` yields a pointer to the second element of the first row. So the second element of the first row is set to `'B'`.

This expression `(*ptr+1)[1]`yields the first element of the second row and it is set to `2`.

The second element of the second row stays uninitialized.

As a result the output is

```
(A,B)(2, )
```